# Ext.js Combo Box - List issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I want to create an application where the combo box should look like first image below. But when I use a list for the combo box it comes out looking like the second image. The list is not fully shown - it is getting cut. Please suggest me which property to use? The code is as below:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    fieldLabel: 'Location',
    displayField: 'name',
    forceSelection: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    store: 'SalesOrderManager.store.LocationStore',
    typeAhead: true,
    valueField: 'id',
    id: 'LocationComboBox'
}]
```

What it should look like:

[image: Desired Output]

What I'm getting instead:

[image: Current Output]

The full code can be viewed in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7TwDu/).

Comment: Fiddle doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the picker width?  I think you want:

```
matchFieldWidth: false,
listConfig: {
    width: 250
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lagnat, your code is working. I wasted 3-4 hours almost. Thanks again.:)